# Defining type of function which I want to take as an input : Typescript

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

I want to make sure that my input accepts only below function as an argument:

```
  async getAll<T extends Entity>(url: string, params?: any): Promise<T[]> {
     // func body
  }
```

*My function*:

```
  setFunc(getAllFunc: any){
    this.func = getAllFunc;
  }
```

I want to replace `any` with custom type.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use an interface or a type for this.

**Type:**

```
type TGetAllFunc<T extends Entity> = (url: string, params? : any) => Promise<T[]>;
```

**Interface:**

```
interface IGetAllFunc<T extends Entity> {
    (url: string, params? : any): Promise<T[]>;
}
```

Then you can pass in either one to the function(I passed in the Interface here):

```
setFunc(getAllFunc: IGetAllFunc<Entity>){
  this.func = getAllFunc;
}
```

Comment: It says `Generic type 'IGetAllFunc<T>' requires 1 type argument(s)` when I replace `any`

Comment: Oops sorry forget to pass T to `IGetFunc`, I updated the answer. Does it work now?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your function the type of your `getAll` function is as follows:

```
type FunctionType<T> = (string, any) => Promise<T[]>;
```

You can then rewrite your function `setFunc` to take in the function type.

```
setFunc(getAllFunc: FunctionType<T>){
    this.func = getAllFunc;
}
```

It seems like you set `getAllFunc` to class property, so that means that you would need to have your class also generic. so your class would look something like this,

```
type FunctionType<T> = (string, any) => Promise<T[]>;

class SomeClass<T> { // named SomeClass for brevity, use your own name here
    func: FunctionType<T>

    setFunc(getAllFunc: FunctionType<T>){
        this.func = getAllFunc;
    }

    /* ... */
}
```